# UISearchDisplayController strange animation and offset

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have created a `UITableViewController` and added a `UISearchDisplayController` programmatically. There's no storyboard or nib file as I am doing everything programmatically. Everything seems to work perfectly except when I click on the search bar, it animates weirdly and there's some offset left to the bottom of the search bar.

[Here's a video](http://d.pr/v/nwCL) of the behaviour.

And here's the code of Table VC:

```
// Initialize Search Bar
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;

self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;

// Hide the search bar
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44)];
```

I also tried `[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];` on the UITableViewController's implementation but it created another issue, although it seems to fix the animation by some extent leaving some gap at the top and the same gap at the bottom of search bar.

Edit: One more thing to note—it can be seen in the video that the result table view is properly aligned with the search bar. So is there any problem with the implementation of main table view? They are same but the former is aligned properly so I am guessing there's a problem with the table view. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

iOS7 makes programmatically adding these elements unnecessarily difficult. After much testing in my own app, here's how I did it inside of my `UITableViewController`.

```
// _searchBar
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0f)];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;

// _searchController
self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:[self searchBar] contentsController:self];
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsTableView.frame = [self.tableView frame];

// _tableView
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [self.searchController searchBar];
```

Don't worry about hiding the searchBar, as the OS will reset everything to its original state when you hit cancel.